# Jquery Autocomplete JSON string parsing error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to use [Jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) in my web application but encounter issues. I am developing my application in ASP.NET and JQuery.

Here's the part of the Autocopmlete 'succes' function:

```
success: function (data) {
     response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
         return {
              label:  item.key,
             value: item.value
            }
       }));
     },
```

My webservice returns the following JSON:

```
"[{"key":"Bread","value":"3"}]"
```

When I run it I get  Javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '42' in [{"key":"bread","value":"3"}]
```

It looks like that the returned JSON is not in the right format for the $.map function from what I can tell. Also the result might return several items, not just one as seen above.

Can anyone help me solve this issue.
I am using `JSON` as the `dataType` and `GET` as the `type` in the Ajax call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I simply suggest you instead of using any other method you can use :

```
success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    var jsonArray = JSON.parse(data);  // Normal way
}
```

Other way

```
success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    var jsonArray = $.parseJSON(data); // using jQuery
}
```

In this way it will be converted to a simple JavaScript object which you can easily manipulate on your UI/DOM.

Comment: Thanks, I used your solution with a $.each loop and it works. I've needed to parse the result and then use the for each for put them in an array

Comment: Its a pleasure for me to help you.

Comment: Thanks, Ankur. So Idan's issue was that he was not calling the `$.each` method on an object? He was calling the method on just a `string`? I used your solution and it worked for me. When I printed out `response` (not using JSON.parse) in my app, I saw the actual content of the object (`string` type). However, after using `JSON.parse(response)`, I saw `[Object object], [Object object], ...` with type `object`

Answer (score 0):

You're right -- your JSON is an array which contains a single object. You're expecting just that object.

Try modifying your code like so:

```
success: function (data) {
  data = data[0];
```

Comment: From FireBug:  
data.d: "[{"key":"bread","value":"3"}]"

$.map(data.d[0]): [Exception: TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '0' in []

Comment: Now you're changing things. Is `"[{"key":"bread","value":"3"}]"` the value of `data` or `data.d`? What exactly is in `data`?

Comment: data.d = "[{"key":"bread","value":"3"}]" and data = d: "[{"key":"bread","value":"3"}]" (from firebug)